# array of words then nested for loop to check the chars

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, nested

hey guys i'm a newby to programming in java and i'm trying to figure out why i'm getting a string out of bounds on my secondary loop. I'm trying to create a spell checker & i'm not sure maybe i'm not doing this exactly right. I'm trying to check the word of a sentence and compare it to the other array of words and char each character until end of the length of toCheck, but doesn't work :\

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! thank you in advance

```
    public static String suggestions (String toCheck, String [] words, Scanner kb)
   {//start
      int length=toCheck.length(),total=0, count = 0;
      for(int x = 0;x<words.length;x++)
      {
         if(words[x].charAt(0)==(toCheck.charAt(0)))
            for(int j = 0;j<length-1;j++)
            {
               if(toCheck.charAt(j)==words[x].charAt(j))
                  count++;

            }
         if(count>=((words[x].length())/2))
            total++;}

      System.out.println(total);
      //System.out.printf("Not found - %s",toCheck); 
      //System.out.println("\nChoices 1 leave as it 2. Type replacement 3 Pick one " + Arrays.toString(suggest));
      return toCheck;

   }//end of suggestions
```

error message shown

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
at CSCD210HW4.suggestions(CSCD210HW4.java:59)
at CSCD210HW4.main(CSCD210HW4.java:44)
```

Comment: Maybe you are comparing words of different lengths in the same loop? You should need to add a break condition if one of the compared words meets it end.

Comment: @Averroes i like that idea! not exactly sure how to do that though! would it look like? this for(int j = 0;j<length-1;j++)
            {
               if(toCheck.charAt(j)==words[x].charAt(j))
               {count++;
                  if(j==(toCheck.length())-1)
                     break;
               else if(j==(words[x].length()-1))
               break;}
            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use compareTo instead of manual checking for different character. It will be more easy.

For example

```
  count = Math.abs(words[x].compareTo(toCheck)); 
  //It will return the difference of character in both string.
  // Suppose words[x] = "abc" and toCheck = "adc" then count will be 1.
```

Comment: thank you!!! thats an awesome way!! i'll have to remember that! really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

length is the size of the word to check.

you're trying to access words[x].charAt(j) which does not have to exist.
j  is the length of the string toCheck

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code:

```
public class check {
    public static  boolean suggestions (String toCheck, ArrayList<String> words)
    {
        for(String word: words )
        {
             return (toCheck.toLowerCase().equalsIgnoreCase(word));
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```